# Configure a SpringBoot application to connect javax validation messages to messages.properties file

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot

I am trying to plug in a messages.properties file to my `@Valid` annotation validations.  I can't get the `@Valid` annotations to connect to the `messages.properties` file.

It is a spring-boot configuration.  The `messages.properties` file is in the resources folder and I have added this been to a configuration file

```
@Configuration
public class config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }
```

The controller I am hoping to see the messages in (before I start trying to get them displaying in the Thymeleaf template) is along the lines

```
RequestMapping(value = "sampleurl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String requestSamplePost(@ModelAttribute @Valid SampleForm     sampleForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

//hoping to see the message from the messages file here  
System.out.println("Binding Result: " + bindingResult.toString());
 ...
```

The pojo has this content

```
public class SampleForm {
    @NotEmpty ()
    @Email()
    private String email;
    …
```

The messages.properties file has this kind of content

```
NotEmpty.SampleForm.email=THIS IS BESPOKE MESSAGE 1
Email.SampleForm.email=THIS IS BESPOKE MESSAGE 2
```

The output I am getting is

```
Field error in object 'sampleForm' on field 'email': rejected value  [jj]; 
codes [Email.sampleForm.email,Email.email,Email.java.lang.String,Email]; 
arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: 
codes [sampleForm.email,email]; arguments []; 
default message [email],[Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@6679140b,^[^{}|]*$]; 
default message [not a well-formed email address]
```

Can anyone

1. confirm that I should be able to see the bespoke message in the bindingerrors object if everything is configured properly.
2. tell me where I might have gone wrong ?  I'm sure this all the configuration I needed to do in a standard Spring-MVC app that I worked on before but maybe I am missing a step or is a different configuration needed with SpringBoot?

Comment: Have you looked at the error? And compared the given codes in there with the codes you actually have in your `messages.properties` small hint `Email.sampleForm.email` != `Email.SampleForm.email`. Also Spring Boot already configures a message source for you no need to configure it yourself (again).

Comment: Thanks for that.  I had made that typo and not noticed.  In the end I've downloaded the sample code from Spring and  I've realised now the bespoke message doesn't appear as the default message in Java code (i.e. answer to #1 appears to be no I shouldn't expect to see the message in the print output.  I'll concentrate on the Thymeleaf code instead.